# Rails server not starting up I'm getting this error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im not able to get my rails server started been searching for hours now. Can anyone help?I have added the code bellow

```
/Users/Iain/rails_projects/ali_bodill_photogrphy/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `ali_bodill_photogrphy' for main:Object (NameError)
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/activesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:591:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `each'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:590:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /Users/Iain/rails_projects/ali_bodill_photogrphy/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Iain/rails_projects/ali_bodill_photogrphy/config.ru:3:in `require'
from /Users/Iain/rails_projects/ali_bodill_photogrphy/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/Iain/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/Iain/rails_projects/ali_bodill_photogrphy/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/Iain/rails_projects/ali_bodill_photogrphy/config.ru:in `<main>'
```

Im really new to this.

```
ali_bodill_photogrphy.application.configure do
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
config.cache_classes = false

# Do not eager load code on boot.
config.eager_load = false

# Show full error reports and disable caching.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

# Don't care if the mailer can't send.
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

# Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
config.active_support.deprecation = :log

# Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

# Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
# This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
# number of complex assets.
config.assets.debug = true
```

# Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

# Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end

Comment: Show your `config/environments/development.rb` file.

Comment: I supppose you have a misspelled variable or method `ali_bodill_photogrphy`.

Comment: Environment configuration files usually start with `Rails.application.configure`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're new, let tell you about the debugging process

--

**Error**

The error is shown here (first line):

> undefined local variable or method `ali_bodill_photogrphy' for
>   main:Object (NameError)

The fundamental bottom line with "computer" related problems is there has to be a logical *cause* of the error. The logical place to begin looking for the causes of the problem is to identify *what* the problem is; hence looking for the error message

In your case, the message says that you don't have the method `ali_bodill_photography` on `line 1` of your `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
ali_bodill_photogrphy.application.configure do
```

--

**Fix**

This is a problem with the core of Rails. If you've changed this file, you'll want to change it back; or look at the other files to gauge what the "correct" method needs to be.

I'll give you some examples from our Rails 4 apps:

```
#config/environments/development.rb (4.1.4)
Rails.application.configure do

#config/environments/development.rb (4.0.0)
Appname::Application.configure do

#config/environments/development.rb (3.2)
AppName::Application.configure do
```

Based on the above files, I would recommend looking at your version of Rails, and amending the top of your `development.rb` file to replicate either of the above examples

So if you have Rails 4.1.4 (the latest), you can just replace your `all_bodill_photograph` with `Rails`. If you have a lesser version of Rails, it looks like you'l need to use a constantized version of your application's name - `AppName::Application`

Comment: thanks for the detailed help. What I did was open another rails project that is working and I had a look at that file. It had:'SampleApp::Application.configure do' I copied this to the file that I'm having an issue with but changed the name to 'alibodillphotogrphy::Application.configure do' this however still recive this error. '/Users/Iain/rails_projects/ali_bodill_photogrphy/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `alibodillphotogrphy' for main:Object (NameError)'

Comment: You'll need to CamelCase your app name - AliBodillPhotography

Comment: yes, thank you that worked. The seder runs but when I go to local host I now get this error. 'Internal Server Error

You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config.'?